# Android: how to set button (AppCompatButton) background image depending on its enabled state?

Tags: android, button, android-appcompat

I have created two vector images, say `button_active.xml` and `button_inactive.xml`, and added them in drawable folder.

I would like to create an `AppCompatButton`, centered in a `ConstraintLayout`, its size always being 48x48dp. It would display either the active or the inactive image depending on its `enabled` state.

I tried this but can't get this to work:

**Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="TestViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/TestStyle"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:enabled="@{vm.enabled}"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**In styles.xml**

```
<style name="TestStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="background">@drawable/test_button_selector</item>
</style>
```

**In drawable/test_button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_active"
        android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_inactive"
        android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

But this doesn't work. What should I do?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:background` attribute instead of `background`:

```
<style name="TestStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/test_button_selector</item>
</style>
```